# Are van der Waals coefficients independent of temperature?

Tags: gas-laws, van-der-waals-behavior

In the van der Waals equation for real gases, the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are used as respective correction terms for pressure and volume in the ideal gas equation.

I want to know whether the van der Waals coefficients are independent of absolute temperature or not.

Comment: The "formal" constants are just that - constants. However one could certainly have a table of $a$ and $b$ values for different ranges of temperature and pressure. See wikipedia article *real gas* for other equations.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constants a and b in the Van der Waals equation are supposed to be independent of temperature.  But it is important to remember that, even though the Van der Waals equation does a better job of approximating the behavior of real gases than the ideal gas law (over a larger range of parameter values), it too is just approximation that applies only over a limited range of values for the parameters.

Answer (score 7):

The van der waals constant can be directly obtained from the critical temperature and pressure. We have,

> ${a = \frac{27 R^2 T_c^2}  {64 P_c}}$
>
> ${b =  \frac{R T_c }{ 8 P_c}}$

Since, $T_c$ and $P_c$ are constants, we can conclude that the van der waals constants are really "constants."